# NextJs how to deal with fetching and a loop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a question how can I deal with fetching through loop in getStaticProps, because when I do that the array is empty. It is caused by asynchronous code. If I pass ID array and put logic into react component it works fine. Should I stick with component approach or do it in getStaticProps. If getStaticProps how can I pass data?

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async (context) => {
  
  const assetsId = await getDataFromMongo();
const assetsArray = [] as Asset[];
      console.log(assetsId);
      assetsId.forEach((asset) => {
        const getAssets = async () => {
          const response = await fetch(
            `https://rest.coinapi.io/v1/assets/${asset}`,
            {
              method: "GET",
              headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "X-CoinAPI-Key": "API KEY",
              },
            }
          );
          const data = await response.json();
          assetsArray.push(data);
        };
        getAssets();
      });
      console.log(assetsArray);
  return {
    props: {
      assets: assetsId,
    },
    revalidate: 1,
  };
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use `Promise.all` here and wait for all the promises to resolve. Right now your promises resolve too late (the response has already been sent to the client and the array is empty.

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async (context) => {
  const assetsId = await getDataFromMongo();

  const promises = assetsId.map(async (id) => {
    const response = await fetch(`https://rest.coinapi.io/v1/assets/${id}`, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "X-CoinAPI-Key": "API KEY",
      },
    });

    return response.json();
  });

  return {
    props: {
      assets: await Promise.all(promises),
    },
    revalidate: 1,
  };
};
```

Also heads up, you'll *probably* want to increase your `revalidation` as 1 second will barely make a difference over just using `getServerSideProps` and you'll be hitting this coin api a lot!